# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP set to GNOME even though I'm running unity 7

Tags: unity, xorg, gnome-session, unity-control-center

Running Ubuntu 16.10

Something is setting `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to `GNOME`, and it's messing up my unity-control-center. If I run `bash -x` it's not being set in the output, but can still be seen by running `env`.

In my `$HOME/.xsession-errors` I see it being set to Unity, but something later must be overriding it.

How do I go about debugging this to find the culprit?

Comment: Still investigating myself, but now also see that I am missing DESKTOP_SESSION in the environment, and as a result gnome-session is being started with --session=<blank>

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. There was a syntax error in an export in my $HOME/.profile (a multiline value) which for some reason now causes all set-env from gnome-session to fail. Once the bad export was removed, everything works.